# cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception

Tags: python, linux, opencv, centos

I was browsing StackOverflow, and of course I found a similar post about the problem!

["cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60651352/cvvideocaptureopen-videoiocv-images-raised-opencv-exception)

However, as it has been 5 months with no answers on that, I've opened a new thread. Here it goes!

I've got an error when I try to run  cv2.VideoCapture(url).

The box is running openCV 4.4, Centos 7, Raspberry PI 4, ARMV7L. See source and logs bellow.

I believe it's related to NumPy library, however, I'm still debugging it.

Does anyone has experienced the same? Any ideas on how to solve it?
Please see the source and log messages bellow.
Best wishes,
I

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import random, string

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eyeCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')                                                                                                                                                    
url = 'rtsp://<ip-direction:port/path>'

print("Running py script detectFacesEyes.py")
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(url)

print(video_capture)

while True:
   ret, img = video_capture.read()
   print(img)
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

   faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=3, 
   minSize=(30, 30))

   for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
      cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0, 0), 2)
      roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
      roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

      eyes = eyeCascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)

      for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
          cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0), 2)

      if len(eyes) != 0:
          crop_img = img[y-99:y+h+99, x-36:x+w+36]
          if len(crop_img) != 0:
              letters = string.ascii_lowercase
              result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(12))
              status = cv2.imwrite(result_str+".jpg", crop_img)


  #This breaks on 'q' key
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

  video_capture.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

python detectFacesEyes.py
Running py script detectFacesEyes.py
[ERROR:0] global /usr/local/src/opencv_build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (142) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.4.0-dev) /usr/local/src/opencv_build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): rtsp://ip-direction:port/path in function 'icvExtractPattern'

<VideoCapture 0xb196d710>
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "detectFacesEyes.py", line 19, in 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0-dev) /usr/local/src/opencv_build/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'

Comment: can you access the stream with a videoplayer? You should try to reduce the code to a minimal runnable code that shows the behaviour.

Comment: Hi Micka, yes. RTSP channel is accessible. I've tested with the VLC player. Furthermore, I have the very same code running in another box: same OS Centos 7, but a different arch x86_64.  That one, which throws the error is Rasp PI 4, Centos 7, ARMv7L

It seems the error is within libraries. My first guess was numpy vector structures, however, I was able to debug it, because I can not even print the result of video_capture command.  line 10 "print(video_capture)"